# Is there a way to parse multiple words in a string?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, substring

I'm working on a flutter search bar where the results from the buildSuggestions are used to populate the buildResults widget. The example from the flutter tutorial (boring flutter show) generates a string. I want to be able to select and print from the string both id and season. I tried substring but that won't always work since the colors have different length.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final colors = [
  {'id': 'red', 'season': 'winter',},
  {'id': 'green', 'season': 'spring',}
];


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile (
          title: Card(
          child: Text (colors[index].toString()))),
          itemCount: colors.length))),
          
);}

}
```

OUTPUT
{id: blue, season: winter}
{id: green, season: spring}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Colors[index] will give out the content of the item at that index since that is a list. The data at the index however is a map, hence why you get the "{id: blue, season: winter}"

Try using this code for your Text widget as this extracts the data from the maps that are within your list.

```
Text("${colors[index]['id']} and ${colors[index]['season']}")
```

Comment: I knew I was overthinking it. 

I tried both colors.[index].id and colors.elementAt(index).id. 

Worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Actually, that still throws the 'type String is not a subtype of the type int of index' for buildSuggestions but displays the id and season in buildResults.  and

Comment: Actually, that still throws the 'type String is not a subtype of the type int of index' for buildSuggestions but displays the id and season in buildResults.  and

Text("${suggestionList[index].toString()}") is the only thing that works. 

This code throws errors also - Text("${suggestionList[index].toString()['cid'}")

What I am trying to accomplish: 
Create a ListView.builder for buildSuggestions -> returns only ['id'] and ['season'] and when the user clicks on one of the suggestions from the list, buildResults returns the other key, value pairs.